# How can I use multiple Arduino-read photo resistors without interference between them?

Tags: arduino, capacitor, interference, photoresistor

I'm working on a prototype that utilizes a combination of photo resistors and LEDs to simulate a "tripwire" to detect when a coin falls through a clear tube. When using one tube, one photo resistor, and one LED, the analog readings from the photo resistor are pretty reliable; however, when using this combination for a pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters, the readings from each photo resistor are all over the place. Some suggested that this might be noise interference between the arduino and the circuit.

Could someone give me an idea of what my problem might be and a possible means of alleviating said problem?

Comment: Schematic, please.

Comment: and a picture of your setup

Comment: Is this question still valid?. I agreed that a picture would help. Photo-resistors are 'passive' in the sense they do not 'send' physical signals. They do not 'interfere' each other by sending 'infrared' noise -which could indeed be the case of using multiple Infrared LED detectors.

Answer (score -1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa86iK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think this will work.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. For this to be a truly useful answer down the line of time (and avoid confused downvotes and the like) you would do very well to add an explanation as to why you think this will solve the problem. I'm pretty sure you're just drawing exactly what the OP has, and as such it won't solve anything, but maybe your -in body- explanation will convince me otherwise.

Comment: I am not sure what "op" stands for. I also don't know why it won't solve the problem. It should give you an analog input on your analog pins and should allow you to (in theory) read an infinite number of photocells.

Comment: Were the "Orginal Poster"'s (alt: Original Post) question "Help, I don't know how to connect multiple sensors to my Arduino", that would have been a very good response. Unfortunately, that's one of the very few things I'm absolutely sure he/she isn't asking.